# OutOfMemoryError in test with jUnit

Tags: java, junit

When i Test my programe with jUnit, i have errors of

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

. How can i manage the memory size for testing?

Comment: How are you running the tests?

Comment: What IDE is that? Please add some more info, otherwise people will not be able to help you

Comment: In your IDE there must be options for test running. Write in JVM options `-Xmx1024m`.

Comment: @Bry6n: really what is the point of such comment in this post? I have seen similar for many questions, but when people are asking "I do not know how to do" something, it is not necessary they have tried anything.

Comment: @Bry6n : i test a method in my program, when i change parameter of table i have  java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

Comment: @korifey Xmx1024m there is this option but not for testing :/

Comment: @user1149157 Do you use Eclipse? If so, it creates Run configuration for launch of Unit test by "right-clicking". So you can edit this configuration. I believe other IDEs behaves similar.

Comment: @user1149157 please provide more details in the problem description. I always say that I need more money, but people can't help me. I wander why.

Answer (score 1):

One possible reason for this is keeping lots of data in instance fields of the test classes.

You have to understand that JUnit will create a new object of the test class for each test method in the class (in order to avoid having the tests influence each other), and will keep references to all those objects.

Therefore instance fields in test classes should not refer to large amounts of data or, if that is really necessary, theyy have to be set to `null` in a teardown method.

**Update:** The problem described above was apparently only present in older versions of JUnit.

Comment: i want to know how to manage memory for testing, because i cannot make  -Xmx1024m for test file ! i'm under Netbeans

Comment: Nulling the fields is not necessary. They will be garbage collected even without it.

Comment: @Esko Luontola: no, the objects referred to by those fields will NOT be garbage collected until the entire test suite has finished. If you have a test class with 20 test methods and an instance field containing a 10MB byte array, then you will need 200+ MB of heap memory or the test run will abort with an OutOfMemoryError.

Comment: @Michael Borgwardt: Wrong. The objects are eligible for garbage collection right after the test method has been executed. It would be foolish if it would work some other way. A look at the JUnit 4.10's code (org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner#runChild) shows that it doesn't keep hold of the objects, and the experiment http://pastebin.com/Hdt7vvYP (it allocates 100MB per test) proves it also: Using -Xmx160M it passes with a couple of allocation retries (because of lazy GC) and using -Xmx310M all allocations succeed on first try (jdk1.6.0_24 64bit Win7).

Comment: @Esko Luontola: OK, you have convinced me that I doesn't work like that, but I am absolutely certain that JUnit really did work that foolishly in the past - this was however some years ago and in JUnit 3

Comment: Yes, JUnit 3 appears to work like that. junit.framework.TestSuite#addTestMethod calls junit.framework.TestSuite#createTest which instantiates one object per method, and they are executed much later when junit.framework.TestCase#run is called for all suites and tests. So in JUnit 3 the allocation should be done in `setUp()` and freed in `tearDown()`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Eclipse IDE; click on run from the menu on top and select run configurations. A dialog box will appear. Select the test that you are running and click on the arguments tab. type: -Xmx1024m and click apply. Run it again and see if it throws the same exception. If it does, the method under test is probably causing the problem. That happens when you have recursive calls in a cycle. Hope that helps.